# Upgrading from 3.0 to 3.2

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I'm tying to upgrade the Zabbix Server from 3.0 to 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 that I didn't install by myself and I don't know if it was istalled form repository or sources. I've done all the necessary backups and when I'm tying to execute this command

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-agent`

I get this message

> Skipping zabbix-server-mysql, it is not installed and only upgrades
>   are requested.

I'm using MySQL with a working DB for Zabbix. Can the Zabbix Server be installd without the zabbix-server-mysql package and still use the MySQL database? If yes, does it mean that the previous user installed it from sources and not from the repository?

I didn't find similar problems searching the net so maybe someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dpkg-query -l 'zabbix*'
```

You'll see if Zabbix has been installed through the packages.
According to the error message you have, I would say definitely no.

Do a typical install through the packages, re-enter the login/pass of your MySQL DB and it will upgrade it. Don't forget to make a backup first, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see 'rc'  zabbix-server-mysql so it means that the file was removed. Can Zabbix function without it?